# Creating & maintaining flowcharts in Vim

Tags: alignment, ascii-art

Here is a simple text-based flowchart I made in Vim for a weblog post:

```
               [DNS request]
                    |
                    |
                 [Adsuck]
                    |
                    |
                 <block?>
                    |
                   / \
                  /   \
              <YES>    \-> <NO> --> [unbound lookup]
                |
                v
            [noop.py]
                |
                |
        <Have noop script?>
                |
               / \
              /   \
           <YES>   \-> <NO> --> [serve empty GIF]
             |
             v
    [serve noop script]
```

The problem is, is that it can be rather painstaking; change one thing, and you need to change everything.

Is there anything I can do to make this easier? I don't really care about the above layout of the flowchart *as such*, as long as it looks flowchart-y it's fine. Flowcharts may also be horizontal as far as I'm concerned, although I prefer vertical like above.

Answer (score 15):

Rather than use vim to directly attempt to manipulate ASCII art, why not use vim to edit a file format that defines a graph?

The [dot format](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf) is a fairly compact way to represent graphs. A rough approximation of the graph  you outlined in your example would look like this:

```
digraph {
  start -> adsuck;
  adsuck -> block;
  block -> noop[label="yes"];
  block -> unbound[label="no"];
  noop -> serve_noop[label="yes"];
  noop -> serve_empty[label="no"];
}
```

Then you can use Perl's [Graph::Easy](http://search.cpan.org/~tels/Graph-Easy/lib/Graph/Easy.pm) module to render the graph into a variety of output formats, including ASCII text. It can also produce HTML pages, SVG, PNG, et cetera.

Install Perl if you don't have it, install Graph::Easy (`cpanm Graph::Easy`, see [here](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) for details). This will give you a `graph-easy` command-line tool. Create `yourgraph.dot` or whatever (vim has syntax knowledge of the dot format already, and there are also [related plugins](https://github.com/wannesm/wmgraphviz.vim)).

Run `graph-easy --as ascii yourgraph.dot output.txt` and you'll get something like this:

```
                      +-------------+
                      |    start    |
                      +-------------+
                        |
                        |
                        v
                      +-------------+
                      |   adsuck    |
                      +-------------+
                        |
                        |
                        v
+------------+  no    +-------------+
|  unbound   | <----- |    block    |
+------------+        +-------------+
                        |
                        | yes
                        v
+------------+  yes   +-------------+
| serve_noop | <----- |    noop     |
+------------+        +-------------+
                        |
                        | no
                        v
                      +-------------+
                      | serve_empty |
                      +-------------+
```

It's not quite as pretty, but it's a heck of lot easier to edit the dot file than to manipulate all the ASCII art. I found that [this article](http://melp.nl/2013/08/flow-charts-in-code-enter-graphviz-and-the-dot-language/) was a pretty nice write-up about building flowcharts with the dot format.

Answer (score -1):

You might try the [DrawIt](https://github.com/vim-scripts/DrawIt) plugin.

> DrawIt is a plugin which allows one to draw lines left, right, up,
>   down, and along both slants. Optionally one may "cap" the lines with
>   arrowheads.  One may change the horizontal, vertical, slant, and
>   crossing characters to whichever characters one wishes.

Comment: How do I use this to create & maintain flowcharts?

Comment: Since it is geared toward drawing ASCII art it could lower the amount of pain when you have to refactor.  But @JoshPetrie is probably right that using dot would be better.

Comment: Please read our [policy on plugin-recommendation answers](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/99/24) and add some detail. A specific example of how to configure the plugin (if necessary) and activate it would be helpful.